# looping through array of associative arrays to remove some data adds wrong data to second item

Tags: php, arrays, loops, build

This is the result of a query to the DB:

```
array(2) {
    [0] array(21) {
        ["model_id"] 218
        ["total"] 10
        ["make"] "maker_a"
        ["model_name"] "some_name"
        ["picture"] "some_picture.jpg"
        ["color"] "Black"
        [1] 0
        [2] 0
        [3] 0
        [4] 6
        [5] 3
        [6] 1
        [7] 0
        [8] 0
        [9] 0
        [10] 0
        [11] 0
        [12] 0
        [13] 0
        [14] 0
        [15] 0
    }
    [1] array(21) {
        ["model_id"] 219
        ["total"] 10
        ["designer"] "maker_a"
        ["model_name"] "some_other_name"
        ["picture"] "some_other_picture.jpg"
        ["color"] "White"
        [1] 0
        [2] 0
        [3] 0
        [4] 5
        [5] 5
        [6] 0
        [7] 0
        [8] 0
        [9] 0
        [10] 0
        [11] 0
        [12] 0
        [13] 0
        [14] 0
        [15] 0
    }
}
```

I want to get rid of the items with value = 0, so I tried this loop:

```
$results = [];

foreach ($models as $i) {
    foreach ($i as $key => $value) {

        if ($value != 0 || !is_numeric($value)) {

            $result[$key] = $value;
        }

    }
    if (isset($result)) {
        $results[] = $result;

    }

}

var_dump($results);
```

but for some reason the result is incorrect, an item with value != 0 gets added in the second item, the value that is correctly present in the first item as [6] 1 gets
added to the second item where there were only [4] 5 and [5] 5. I don't get the reason of this result.

```
array(2) {
    [0] array(9) {
        ["model_id"] 218
        ["total"] 10
        ["makes"] "maker_a"
        ["model_name"] "some_name"
        ["picture"] "some_picture.jpg"
        ["color"] "Black"
        [4] 6
        [5] 3
        [6] 1
    }
        [1] array(9) {
        ["model_id"] 219
        ["total"] 10
        ["designer"] "maker_a"
        ["model_name"] "some_other_name"
        ["picture"] "some_other_picture.jpg"
        ["color"] "White"
        [4] 5
        [5] 5
        [6] 1 <---- THIS DOESN'T BELONG HERE!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Damn, for some reason the loop is posting the last $result variable in the next item. Solution was adding `unset($result);` after insertion in the $results array:

```
$results = [];

    foreach ($models as $i) {
        foreach ($i as $key => $value) {

            if ($value != 0 || !is_numeric($value)) {

                $result[$key] = $value;
            }

        }
        if (isset($result)) {
            $results[] = $result;
            unset($result); // <--- HERE

        }

    }

    var_dump($results);
```